# PHP: Carrusel Bootstrap que muestre fotos de 5 en 5

Tags: php, html, bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

Estoy intentando modificar un carrusel Bootstrap para que muestre imágenes de 5 en 5; las imágenes están almacenadas en un directorio de mi web, pero para saber cuáles se han de mostrar en cada momento he de hacer una llamada a mi base de datos (además de las imágenes en sí también pretendo mostrar otra información relacionada cuando consiga que el carrusel funcione bien).

Éste es el codigo:

```
<?php

    $id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

    include("conexion.php");

    $sql = "SELECT titulo_cancion, titulo_disco, nombre_autor, ano  
            FROM listas NATURAL JOIN canciones NATURAL JOIN votan NATURAL JOIN discos NATURAL JOIN publican NATURAL JOIN autores
            WHERE id_usuario = $id_usuario AND nota = 5
            ORDER BY fecha_voto DESC";

    $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

    $filas = array();

    while($filas[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados));

    array_pop($filas);

    $maximo = sizeof($filas);

?>

<div id="carrusel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">

    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <?php

            foreach($filas as $clave => $valor) 
            {
                $clave = $contador * 5;

                echo '<div class="carousel-item'; echo ($contador == 0) ? ' active">' : '">';

                    if($clave >= $maximo)
                    {
                        $contador = 0;
                        $clave = 0;
                    } 

                    for($i = $clave; $i <= $clave + 4; $i++) 
                    {
                        #$titulo_cancion = utf8_encode($filas[$i]['titulo_cancion']);
                        $titulo_disco = utf8_encode($filas[$i]['titulo_disco']);
                        #$nombre_autor = utf8_encode($filas[$i]['nombre_autor']);
                        $ano = $filas[$i]['ano'];

                        if(strpos($nombre_autor, ", The")) $nombre_autor = "The ".substr($nombre_autor, 0, strpos($nombre_autor, ", The"));

                        $decada = substr($ano, 0, 3)."0s";

                        if(strpos($titulo_disco, "/")) $nombre_foto = substr($titulo_disco, 0, strpos($titulo_disco, "/"));
                        elseif(strpos($titulo_disco, ":")) $nombre_foto = substr($titulo_disco, 0, strpos($titulo_disco, ":"));
                        else $nombre_foto = $titulo_disco;

                        #$recopilatorio = $ano;

                        echo '<img class="img-fluid mr-2" src="imagenes/'.$decada.'/'.$ano.'/'.$nombre_foto.'.jpg" width="214.01225" height="214.01225">';

                        if($i == $maximo - 1) break;
                    }

                    $contador++;

                echo '</div>';
            }   

        ?>

    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carrusel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carrusel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

El código "funciona" pero existe el obvio problema de que cuando el `foreach` se acaba el carrusel empieza otra vez desde 0 aunque la última foto mostrada no haya sido exactamente la última de la colección; por ejemplo:

Para 7 fotos se hacen 7 recorridos del `foreach`, de `$clave` 0 a `$clave` 6, pero dada la lógica interna del `for` las fotos se muestran en dos tandas, de la 0 a la 4 y de la 5 a la 6; por tanto, cuando el `foreach` llega finalmente a la  `$clave` 6 el `for` está mostrando (por 4ª vez) la tanda de fotos 0-4, pero a continuación no aparece la tanda 5-6, sino que aparece nuevamente la 0-4 puesto que `$clave` vuelve a ser 0.

Este problema no se da cuando la última tanda de fotos a mostrar coincide con la última `$clave`, cosa que ocurre cuando hay 5 fotos (y todos sus múltiplos) o menos y para algunos otros números como 6, 8, 12 y 16 (creo que son los únicos para los que no hay problemas).

La solución sería decirle al `foreach` cada vez que se reinicie que tenga en cuenta qué tanda de fotos fue la última mostrada. He intentado encontrar alguna relación matemática entre el número de fotos y el 5 calculando restos y cocientes pero de momento no veo nada.

Otro comportamiento que me llama la atención es que si sólo hay una foto que mostrar, el carrusel no funciona, no hay deslizamiento. No sé si esto es algo propio de Bootstrap, pero en cualquier caso mis tandas son de cinco fotos y no de una, por lo que lo lógico sería que no hubiera deslizamiento sólo si no hay al menos seis fotos.

En fin, a ver si a alguien se le ocurre algo. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he optado por limitar el carrusel para que no se deslice eternamente:

1) He añadido la opción `data-wrap="false"` dentro de `<div id="carrusel"...>`

2) He modificado el código PHP para que el `foreach` se rompa si se rompe el `for`:

```
    ...

    if($i == $maximo - 1)
    {
        $romper = true;
        break;
    } 
}

if($romper) break;

...
```

Además de esta manera evito que el carrusel se deslice si hay menos de 6 fotos, con lo cual mato dos pájaros de un tiro.